# How to access other related model data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a user profile page and I want to retrieve the data from my **User** model and **UserProfile** model. But I have a problem in getting the result. Here's what I did:

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    /*
    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->admin;
    }
    */

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

**UserProfile model**

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_profile';

    protected $fillable = [
        'phone',
        'address'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then I access the relation in my ProfileController

```
  public function getProfile($username) {

        $user = User::with('user_profile')->where('username', $username)->get();

        dd($user);



    }
```

And I got this error:

```
Call to undefined relationship [user_profile] on model [App\User].
```

The **user_profile** is my table name

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. Write relationship between user & user profile in User Model. Then call.

Comment: I already have relationship. Wait Ill update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper relationship name:

```
$user = User::with('profile')->where('username', $username)->first();
```

Also, in this case you should use the `first()` method to get an user object.

Comment: So other than `User` and `UserProfile` I need also to have a relation in my `ProfileController`?

Comment: @Jerielle you've just updated your question with proper relationship code, so now you need just use it as I described in my answer.

Comment: Ok ill try that :)

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought that inside `with('')` is the table name haha. Thanks for the help